# truth table, how to build a truth table with these informations

Tags: logic

I would like to know how to build a truth table with these information Please?

- If *Mike hits the wall on the east* OR *on the west*, then *Mike goes
  backwards* *30 steps*, then *Mike turn to a random direction* AND *goes
  forward again*.

Comment: Find the atomic propositions : $p$ : "Mike hits the wall on the east" , $q$ : Mike hits the wall on the west", $r$ "Mike goes backwards 30 steps", $s$ : "Mike turn to a random direction", $t$ : "Mike goes forward again".

Comment: Then symbolize the complete prop : $((p \lor q) \to r) \to (s \land t)$.